# Blazor wasm hosted application with company AD windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, windows-authentication, webassembly, hosted-app

I am trying to figure out how can I call blazor wasm hosted application to my company's AD directory and get user.identity information.i am just running in circles.i don't want to use identity server or azure Ad.can someone please share code. The actual working code. Company policy is not allowing to use sticky sessions so can't use blazor server. Please any help.much appreciated.code would be much appreciated. I am surprised there is no such code out there. I am using .net 5

Answer (score 0):

You'll really struggle to get this to work - from MS website:

> We don't recommend using Windows Authentication with Blazor Webassembly or with any other SPA framework. We recommend using token-based protocols instead of Windows Authentication, such as OIDC with Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS).

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#windows-authentication

I highly suggest switching to an OIDC implementation instead. ADFS supports this and your company might already have this setup on the network.